# What kind of texture map is this?

Tags: texturing, uv

I recently downloaded a xnalara model and imported it into blender and between the diffuse and normal maps i found these kind of maps.[image]
 the file name says hair_atos.tex and I can't find any info about them. Can someone please tell me what their full name is and what they are supposed to do?

Comment: alb>Albedo? Looks like it used different color channels for separate info

Comment: I suspect that's an albedo mask, used for letting the hair be tinted. The different color channels are used as separate masks for different tints. Total guess though.

Comment: Sorry I meant hair_atos.tex not albm

Comment: @Vanishs its seems to be what the guys said above dude

Comment: The green channel looks like an Alpha map. The blue channel looks like a Lightpack or something similar.

Comment: looks like a diffuse map of a Neptune grass